# Spring security removes all remember me tokens

Tags: java, spring, security, remember-me

I have implemented remember me function in my web service but the problem is when I restart my server based on tomcat, server removes all records from persistent_logins tabel. Here is my servlet configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.bitcointech.*" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.bitcointech.entities" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.databasePlatform">
            org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"  
cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" 
id="transactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.bitcointech.repositories" 
entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory">
</jpa:repositories>
```

Spring security file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/advance**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/changeState**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/history**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/admin"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="token"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/admin" />
    <csrf/>
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="10" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry" />
    </session-management>
    <remember-me token-validity-seconds="31536000" 
        remember-me-parameter="remember-me" 
        data-source-ref="dataSource" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query=
                "select token, password, enabled from users where token = ?"
            authorities-by-username-query=
                "select token, role from user_roles where token = ?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Any ideas how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist cookies to database, you need to add additional beans. Modify your security configuration as follows :

```
<beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" 
class="org.springframework.security.web.
            authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="myAppKey" />
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="jdbcTokenRepository" />
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="UserDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl"> 
    <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false" /> 
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> 
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="UserDetailsService"/> 
    </authentication-provider> 
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Ok, it seems to work but I have a one exception with this:
"org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The user-service-ref attribute cannot be used in combination with childelements 'user-service', 'jdbc-user-service' or 'ldap-user-service'"

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have moved everything from xml to java and my configuration looks like that:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
        {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/advance**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/changeState**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/history**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("token")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/admin").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and().csrf()
            .and().rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(31536000)
            .rememberMeParameter("remember-me").rememberMeCookieName("remember-me")
            .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
            .and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(10000).sessionRegistry(getSessionRegistry());       
        }

        @Bean
        public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() 
        {
            JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
            db.setDataSource(dataSource());
            return db;
        } 

        @Bean(name = "hibernatePersistenceProvider")
        public HibernatePersistenceProvider hibernatePersistenceProvider() 
        {
            return new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
        }

        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() 
        {
            DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/arbitraz");
            driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("postgres");
            driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("alan12");
            return driverManagerDataSource;
        }

        @Bean(name = "savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler")
        public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() 
        {
            SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
            handler.setTargetUrlParameter("targetUrl");
            return handler;
        }

        @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf() 
        {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            bean.setPackagesToScan("com.bitcointech.entities");
            bean.setDataSource(dataSource());
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("hibernate.databasePlatform", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
            prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
            prop.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
            bean.setJpaProperties(prop);
            bean.setPersistenceProvider(hibernatePersistenceProvider());
            return bean;
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
        {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource())
                    .usersByUsernameQuery(
                            "select token, password, enabled from users where token = ?")
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select token, role from user_roles where token = ?");
        }

        @Bean
        public SessionRegistry getSessionRegistry() 
        {
            return new SessionRegistryImpl();
        }
}
```